# Play Framework sbt assembly jar running error :- "No root server path supplied"

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean, playframework-2.6

I built play framework project jar with sbt assembly command. when I run the jar with Java -jar "jarName.jar" it throws error "No root server path supplied" any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem when I build a fat jar of my project with this plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")
```

and using

```
sbt assembly
```

and running it with

```
java -jar .\myproject-assembly-1.0.jar
```

This went away when I used:

```
sbt dists
```

it will create a zip file containing your application in:

```
\target\universal\myproject-1.0.zip
```

copy this file to the server where you want to run it, unpack, then go to the bin directory and run the script, it worked for me:

```
Linux  : bin\myproject 
Windows: bin\myproject.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/ProdServerStart.scala#L91

```
val rootDir: File = {
  val path = configuration.getOptional[String]("play.server.dir")
    .getOrElse(throw ServerStartException("No root server path supplied"))
```

Shows that the playframework requires a configuration string play.server.dir to be set before it will run.

This is likely happening because you are just running the jar on the command line, or have not followed the deployment / build instructions, or maybe because there is no default configuration defined.

Play deployment instructions can be found here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Deploying#Deploying-your-application

Comment: What should be the value of play.server.dir ? is there no way to run it in command line ? I can use "run" command in my IDE to run the play java project but same jar not running in IDE terminal ?

Comment: There likely *is* a way to run it just from command line. But I couldn't find out how exactly. All the instructions had various other methods

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.7 the Play documentation has a section on [Using the sbt assembly plugin](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Deploying#Using-the-sbt-assembly-plugin), albeit "not officially supported".

The key part is using `MergeStrategy.concat` for `reference-overrides.conf` files. I also had to do the same for `reference.conf` files.

Comment: I've got to say it still doesn't work for me. I'll update my answer if I can get it working.